# Why is.the program not compiling

Tags: c

This code is not compiling I do not understand what to do

```
#include <stdio.h>

void cough(void)    
{       
    printf("cough\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
}
```

Comment: You seriously need to read a good C book before starting to code. The code is wrong.

Comment: Hint: At least check for the required number of braces for each statement and function.

Comment: First of all, indent your code (e.g. like tha samples in your beginner's C text book). I did it fo you. You see the problem with the `for` loop now?

Comment: You also should tell us what the program is supposed to do. Then it will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: "Not compiling" sounds like something is not working - is there any error message given? What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler expects some code to execute during each iteration of the for loop. If you don't want to execute any code, you need to put an empty statement ( simply `;`) within the loop.